# Telegram Bot with Motion AI

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bots, telegram, motion, smooch

How can I run my telegram bot using the bot I created in motion ai? I did all requested integrations in smooch but the bot is not responding.

Thanks

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I created a bot in motion ai (smooch) then integrated it with Smooch. I created a bot in Telegram (empty one) and authenticated it with Smooch. As I read I think that my Telegram bot is now able to use the motion ai bot without writing any code. I am missing something it seems...

Comment: First, could you test to make sure Smooch itself is passing your messages along? You can quickly do this by configuring an email address to receive your telegram messages: https://app.smooch.io/integrations/email

Comment: I configured an email address as you said and yes smooch is receiving my telegram messages...but no reply on Telegram

Comment: If your reply to an incoming email, does that show up in telegram? Is it just Motion.ai that isn't working here?

Comment: Yes, motion ai is not working because I cannot track the conversation in motion ai conversation reports. Although motion ai bot shows me deployed to smooch message. Note: the motion ai bot is working perfectly on other platforms (fb messenger and web chat)

Comment: This is David from Motion AI. We're working with Smooch to determine where the problem might be.  One of us will update you, thanks!

Comment: Thanks David. Now I can see the replies in Telegram but not the values of the cards that I created in motion ai. Need to check if these cards are compatible in Telegram bots...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a problem in Smooch's forwarding of messages from Telegram to Motion.AI. A fix was deployed on Tuesday, so this should be working again.